# Kubernetes MySQL pod getting killed due to memory issue

Tags: kubernetes

In my Kubernetes 1.11 cluster a MySQL pod is getting killed due to `Out of memory` issue:

```
> kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 8514 (mysqld) score 1011 or
> sacrifice child kernel: Killed process 8514 (mysqld)
> total-vm:2019624kB, anon-rss:392216kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
> kernel: java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0,
> oom_score_adj=828 kernel: java
> cpuset=dab20a22eebc2a23577c05d07fcb90116a4afa789050eb91f0b8c2747267d18e
> mems_allowed=0 kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 28667 Comm: java Kdump: loaded Not
> tainted 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 #1 kernel
```

My questions:

1. How to prevent that my pod gets OOM-killed? Is there a deployment setting I need to enable?
2. What is the configuration to prevent new pod getting scheduled on a node, when there is not enough memory available on said node?
3. We disabled the swap space. Do we need to disable memory overcommitting setting on the host level, setting `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to `0`?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defining a Pod manifest it's a best practice to define `resources` section with `limits` and `requests` for CPU and memory:

```
resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 512Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 256Mi
```

This definition helps the scheduler identifying three Quality of Service ([QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/)) categories:

- Guaranteed
- Burstable
- BestEffort

and pods in the last category are the most expendable.

Comment: Nicola is spot on with that answer! If you want to learn more about the topic, you might be interested in an article I wrote about this last year: https://hackernoon.com/container-resource-consumption-too-important-to-ignore-7484609a3bb7

Comment: Thanks I will go with Guaranteed config for my database pods